# Gas estimation failed Error Deploying Contract

Tags: remix, gas-estimate, binance-smart-chain

I am trying to deploy a contract on Binance test network using remix but every time I try to deploy I get the error `Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }`, if anyone has any ideas on anything just say

Comment: Please, can you share all of your smart contract code?

Comment: try with a different network, it looks like your node rpc is incorrect / not responding